# How to get list of all fields corresponding to a model saved in content type framework in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-contenttypes

I have this requirement in which I have to show two dropdown fields on Django admin page.
The first field will be the **dropdown of all the table names available in my project**, and the second field will be a **dropdown all the available fields of the table selected in 1st dropdown**. The second field will be dynamic based on the selection of the first dropdown. I am planning to handle this by overriding **change_form_template**.

Now, I can show the dropdown of table names by fetching them through content type Django model, But not able to fetch corresponding fields as content type model save the model name as a string. So is there any way not necessarily using Content-Type to achieve such a requirement?

Any help around that will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the Model._meta API to get all the fields for a model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have dependency of another fields right so i think you need to see i give link,then yo get error let me know

link:[hint of dependency field in django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: Basically I was looking for this
`from django.apps import apps
model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
field_list = model._meta.fields`

But the link you have provided is of great help for further work. Thank you